# find pairs from two arrays while A is incresing and B is randomized whose sum is equal to a given value k

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I'm trying to count the pairs from two arrays, that A is  incrementally sorted and B is randomly ordered. And I'm also looking for a K value such that A[]+B[]=K, but with the below code I'm getting 0 which should give 3 in real, so where is my mistake?

```
#include <iostream>

int countPairs(int A[], int B[], int m, int n, int K) {
    bool ispre = false;
    int count = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = n - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int value = K - A[i];
        while (left <= right) {
            int mid = (left + right) / 2;
            if (B[mid] == value) {
                ispre = true;
            } else if (B[mid] > value)
                right = mid - 1;
            else
                left = mid + 1;
        }
        if (ispre)
            count++;
        else {
            // value not found
            return false;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main() {
    int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int B[] = { 4, 1, 3, 5, 8 };

    int m = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    int n = sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0]);
    int K = 10;
    cout << "Count = " << countPairs(A, B, m, n, K);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int arr[] = {};`what's that?

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet?

Comment: I was trying to solve the code and this "int arr[] = {};" was i code because of this, I have edited now

Comment: @manni66 : Sorry.  I was commenting on the edited code.  I hadn't realized you were actually quoting an earlier version.

Comment: You are doing a binary search on the unorderd array.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int countPairs(int A[], int B[], int m, int n, int K) {
    bool ispre = false;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = m - 1;
        int value = K - B[i];
        while (left <= right) {
            int mid = (left + right) / 2;
            if (A[mid] == value) {
                ispre = true;
                count++;
                break;
            } else if (A[mid] > value)
                right = mid - 1;
            else
                left = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int B[] = { 4, 1, 3, 5, 8 };

    int m = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    int n = sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0]);
    int K = 10;
    cout << "Count = " << countPairs(A, B, m, n, K) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2+8=10,5+5=10,6+4=10,7+3=10,so the result should be 4. Just compile and run it, I have verified